# Creating single row pie chart for budget in R with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

To start off, this is my dput:

```
structure(list(Income = 18000, Rent = 7300, Wifi = 477, Gas = 900, 
MTR_Bus = 600, Food = 3000, Total_Expenses = 12277, Remaining_Income = 5723), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

That comes up with a data frame like this:
[image: Data Frame]

I'm trying to create a simple pie chart in R using this budget, though I just need the expenses and income (in other words, I don't need the variables "Total Expenses" or "Remaining Income").

My issue is that the best I can come up with is something like this:

```
bar <- ggplot(data = Budget) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Total_Expenses, fill = row))+coord_polar()
```

I guess my question is two-fold: 1) is this the correct structure for my code and 2) what should I be using for x or fill? I didn't really have much of a good answer from my book I was using.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshape you data using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer()`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

budget_pie <- Budget %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  filter(!grepl("^(Total|Remaining)", name))

ggplot(data = budget_pie, aes(x = "", y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: That's beautiful and exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much!

Just as an aside, why the "pivot_longer" function? I always have trouble understanding the help scripts when I generate them in R.

Comment: As ggplot2 is build on the concept of tidy data, we need `pivot_longer` to reshape your data into long or tidy format, i.e. we want one column with the categories and one column with values. In your case I simply reshape all "columns" of your one-row dataframe by setting `cols = everything()` except that I omitted the `cols=`.